# Spring boot integration tests with additional weba application resource path

Tags: integration-testing, spring-boot

I have an integration test (annotated with @WebAppConfiguration) that needs some additional javascript/html files to be served by the application. I'd like to put those files under src/test/webapp but the content of that directory is not loaded.

I've seen that the WebAppConfiguration annotation allow to override the default src/main/webapp path, but I don't need to completely replace that path.

Is there a way to get what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Spring Boot will serve static files from a folder called `/static` (or `/public` or `/resources` or `/META-INF/resources`) on the classpath. Placing your additional JavaScript and HTML files in `src/test/resources/static` should make them available during your integration tests.